# jQuery - Changing button in a list of multiple forms

Tags: javascript, jquery, spring-boot

I am working on a Spring-Boot application and I am trying to change the image of a button depending on if the user favorites the recipe or not.

Currently the html gets a list of recipes, loops through them and generates a form element and child button for each recipe, so you end up with a list of forms. All forms are being set to the same class and I am dynamically making the button ids different.

index.html

```
<div class="grid-100 row addHover" th:each="recipe : ${recipes}">
    <a th:href="@{|/details/${recipe.id}|}">
      <div class="grid-70">
        <p>
        <form class="test" th:action="@{|/recipes/${recipe.id}/favorite|}" method="post" style="display:inline">
          <button  class="favorite-button-index" th:id="'favorite-button-index' + ${recipe.id}">
            <img th:src="${recipe.userFavorites.contains(#authentication.name)} ? @{/assets/images/favorited.svg} : @{/assets/images/favorite.svg}"
                                             style="height: 12px;">
          </button>
        </form>
        <span th:text="${recipe.name}"> </span>

        </p>
     </div>
     </a>
```

app.js

```
   $(".test").on("submit", function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        $.post(this.action, function (data) {
            console.log(data.favorited)
            var id;
            $('.favorite-button-index').each(function() {
                $(this).click(function(){
                    id = $(this).attr('id');
                    console.log(id)
                    // var imageUrl = (data.favorited) ? '/assets/images/favorited.svg' : '/assets/images/favorite.svg'
                    // $('#id>img').attr('src', imageUrl);
            })

            var imageUrl = (data.favorited) ? '/assets/images/favorited.svg' : '/assets/images/favorite.svg'
            $('#id>img').attr('src', imageUrl);
        });

    });
})
```

In app.js when a individual form is submitted, I'm am trying to grab the child button id when it is clicked, then use that id to determine which button in my list should be changed

data.favorited produces true/false depending on if the recipe has been Favorited.

I have confirmed that the id variable is grabbing the correct button id by console logging the id when the button is clicked, but the images for the button is not updated.

I'm pretty new to JS/jQuery and any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You likely need to separate the variable from the string:

```
 $('#' + id + '>img').attr('src', imageUrl);
```

You could also make it cleaner by using [string interpolation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals#Expression_interpolation) like so:

```
 $(`#${id}>img`).attr('src', imageUrl);
```

Comment: Thank you for your quick response. Your suggestion was correct, I needed to separate the variable. I also had to move my button.each event method outside of the form submit event method and store the id in a global scope. Now the favorite buttons for each recipe work independently.